# Error with jsonobject always empty created from jsonarray not empty

Tags: java, arrays, json

I don't understand why i cant create a valid jsonobject from a jsonarray.

```
String data = IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("articles");
logger.info("Number of articles: " + articles.length());
logger.info("Structure json - " + articles);
for(int i = 0 ; i < articles.length() ; i++){
            JSONObject article = new JSONObject(articles.optJSONObject(i));
            logger.info("Struttura json - " + article);
            //String id          = article.getString("originalLink");
            //System.out.println(id);
}
```

When i do this, articles contains 4 jsonobjects. the length is 4.
But when i create a jsonobject it return 4 times "{}".

Any help?

**This is the Json:**

```
{"articles": [
{
  "originalLink": "ansa.it/economia/articolo1",
  "date": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss",
  "cacheCopyLink": "dfdf.it?aerfmde",
  "author": "Alvaro Tizio",
  "id2": 12345,
  "imagesLink": [
    "http://image1.jpg",
    "http://image2.jpg",
    "http://image3.jpg"
  ],
  "idchaptersList": [
    45656,
    123342,
    2345345
  ],
  "text": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
  "sourceDomain": "sdsdsd.com",
  "title": "a sezione 1.10.33 del \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", scritto da Cicerone nel 45 AC"
},
{
  "originalLink": "ansa.it/economia/articolo1",
  "date": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss",
  "cacheCopyLink": "dfdf.it?aerfmde",
  "author": "Alvaro Tizio",
  "id2": 12345,
  "imagesLink": [
    "http://image1.jpg",
    "http://image2.jpg",
    "http://image3.jpg"
  ],
  "idchaptersList": [
    45656,
    123342,
    2345345
  ],
  "text": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
  "sourceDomain": "sdsdsd.com",
  "title": "a sezione 1.10.33 del \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", scritto da Cicerone nel 45 AC"
},
{
  "originalLink": "ansa.it/economia/wdfsdf",
  "date": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss",
  "cacheCopyLink": "dfdf.it?aerfmde",
  "author": "Alvaro Tizio",
  "id2": 12345,
  "imagesLink": [
    "http://image1.jpg",
    "http://image2.jpg",
    "http://image3.jpg"
  ],
  "idchaptersList": [
    45656,
    123342,
    2345345
  ],
  "text": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
  "sourceDomain": "sdsdsd.com",
  "title": "a sezione 1.10.33 del \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", scritto da Cicerone nel 45 AC"
},
{
  "originalLink": "ansa.it/economia/wdfsdf",
  "date": "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss",
  "cacheCopyLink": "dfdf.it?aerfmde",
  "author": "Alvaro Tizio",
  "id2": 12345,
  "imagesLink": [
    "http://image1.jpg",
    "http://image2.jpg",
    "http://image3.jpg"
  ],
  "idchaptersList": [
    45656,
    123342,
    2345345
  ],
  "text": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
  "sourceDomain": "sdsdsd.com",
  "title": "a sezione 1.10.33 del \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", scritto da Cicerone nel 45 AC"
}
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace this

```
JSONObject article = new JSONObject(articles.optJSONObject(i));
```

with this

```
JSONObject article = articles.optJSONObject(i);
```

Indeed the constructor [`new JSONObject(Object)`](http://javadox.com/org.json/json/20151123/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) will dynamically fill up your `JSONObject` instance by calling all the **public getters** of the provided object, in other words it assumes that the provided object is actually a **Java Bean** which is not the case if you provide a `JSONObject`.

As reminder here is the Javadoc of this constructor:

> Construct a `JSONObject` from an `Object` using **bean getters**. It reflects
>   on all of the public methods of the object. For each of the methods
>   with no parameters and a name starting with "`get`" or "`is`" followed by
>   an uppercase letter, the method is invoked, and a key and the value
>   returned from the getter method are put into the new `JSONObject`. The
>   key is formed by removing the "`get`" or "`is`" prefix. If the second
>   remaining character is not upper case, then the first character is
>   converted to lower case. For example, if an object has a method named
>   "`getName`", and if the result of calling `object.getName()` is "`Larry`
>   `Fine`", then the `JSONObject` will contain "`name`": "`Larry Fine`".

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSONObject article = articles.optJSONObject(i);` solved my problem.
thanks.